# C++ dynamic allocated memory return after crash or forced quit?

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation

I would like to know whether a program crash or user forced quit will return the dynamic allocated memory to the computer. Or the memory will leak until system restart.

Comment: [*In C++, Do I need to deallocate memory before close a program*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446428/in-c-do-i-need-to-deallocate-memory-before-close-a-program)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most modern OSes will automatically reclaim all process memory after the process terminates. Usually, this works by having the OS evict all virtual pages associated with the process from its page table. Consequently, unless you have an old OS or hit a weird OS bug, the memory should be reclaimed.

Answer (score 1):

The memory will be released, the dynamic allocation is an operation managed by the operating system.

Thanks to memory paging and segmentation each process will have its share of memory pages assigned by the operating system, upon the termination of the process such pages will be marked as free and will be reused by successive processes when needed.